# Timer in android to execute after a specific time?

Tags: android

I am using the following code to execute a method after a specific time period say 9seconds.The code works fine only after the first execution.However i want that when the activity is launched the method must be called after 9 secs.Now what happens is the method is called the moment the activity is launched followed by after 9 seconds again it is called.
Following is my code:

```
 private Timer myTimer;
 myTimer = new Timer();
 myTimer.schedule(new TimerTask() 
 {          
    @Override
    public void run() 
    {
        TimerMethod();
    }
 }, 0, 9000);


   private void TimerMethod()
   {
        this.runOnUiThread(Timer_Tick);
   }
  private Runnable Timer_Tick = new Runnable() 
  {
    public void run() 
    {

        //Did some UI Operation 
        Toast.makeText(context, msg, 1000).show();

    }
  };
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use this:

```
 private void TimeMethod() {

    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {

            //TODO after 9 sec
        }
    }, 9000);

}
```

Hope this will be usefull,

Cheers

Comment: I replaced my TimerMethod() with that of Manplescu and wrote    private void TimerMethod() {

          new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {

              @Override
              public void run() 
              {

                  Toast.makeText(context, msg, 1000).show();
              }
          }, 9000);

      }             and the app crashed.May be i cannot write the Toast statement there?

Comment: Same question..this code is from my project and works whitout problems...I will try to make a sample project show it to you

Comment: Thanks Manolescu if you could please :)